# should set state in callback after sorting function?

Tags: javascript, react-native, callback, lodash

in my componentDidMount method I partition the data into two separate lists and then set state of the two lists so my UI can render them. I have two questions:

1. is the componentDidMount() method the appropriate place to partition a list received from an API call?
2. is it possible for the code to attempt to set the state before lodash has completed the partitioning (lets say its a really long list)? if so, I tried a .then() callback but I am getting an error saying .then() is not a function.

componentDidMount() {
    const { data } = this.props;

```
let currentTime = moment();

let sortedPosts = _.partition(this.state.listViewData, function(o) {
  return (o.isActive || (new Date(o.scheduledActiveEnd)) < currentTime);

}).then(() => {
  this.setState({
    futureListViewData: sortedPosts[0],
    currentListViewData: sortedPosts[1]
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is the componentDidMount() method the appropriate place to partition a list received from an API call?

Yes, componentDidMount is a good spot for putting asynchronous code, such as fetching data and then parsing the response.

> is it possible for the code to attempt to set the state before lodash has completed the partitioning (lets say its a really long list)? if so, I tried a .then() callback but I am getting an error saying .then() is not a function.

No, [_.partition](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#partition) is synchronous. It returns an array of arrays, not a promise. If you call _.partition on a large array, the thread will block until its done partioning the array.